# Simple formula conversion

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this formula $Av = (R1+R2)/R2$ and I convert it like this
\begin{align}
Av = {} & (R_1+R_2)/R_2 \\
R_2\cdot Av = {} & R_1+R_2 \\
R_2\cdot Av-R_1 = {} & R_2 \\
R_2(Av-R_1) = {} & R_2 \\
(R_2(Av-R_1))/R_2 = {} & R_2/R_2
\end{align}
and $R_2/R_2 = 1$

Any idea why this wouldn't work? Do I misplace the paranthesis? It feels it.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your mistake is in going from step 3 to step 4. The two terms on the left hand side do not have a common factor of R2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to make $R_2$ the subject of the formula:$$\begin{align}A_v&=\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_2}\\
\therefore R_2\times A_v&=R_1+R_2\\
\therefore R_2\times A_v-R_2&=R_1\\
\therefore R_2(A_v-1)&=R_1\\
\therefore R_2&=\frac{R_1}{A_v-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really really appreciate it! I understand where I went wrong now. However I do not understand where the -1 comes from, could you elaborate?

Comment: $R_2(A_v-1)=R_2\times A_v-R_2\times1=R_2\times A_v-R_2$